# CSS dynamic grid pattern

Tags: css, reactjs, design-patterns, grid

I'm currently working on the following grid using **React**, **SCSS** and the **styled-components** library:

[image]

I will eventually be fetching articles from a database so each card has to be dynamically generated. I'm struggling to make the long white cards (labeled (5) and (10) in the screenshot) dynamically sized.

My main problem is the 5th card needs to have a **grid-row: 1 / span 2**, but the 10th card needs a **grid-row: 3 / span 2** (and the 15th will need **grid-row: 5 / span 2** and so on , etc.), but I cannot hard-code it like that.

How can I automatically increase the grid-row-start for every 5th card?

Here is my React component:

```html
    ...

    return (
                <Grid>
                    <Card>
                        <FlexBox>
                            <div>
                                <Image src="profilePicture.jpg" alt="Image"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Name>Jonathan Walters</Name>
                                <Info>Member</Info>
                            </div>
                        </FlexBox>
                        <Title> (1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Title>
                        <Content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus ...</Content>
                    </Card>
                    
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                    <Card> ... </Card>
                </Grid>
        )
    }
```

(I will eventually be iterating on an array with the map method and return one card component for each element in the array).

Here is my styled.jsx file :

```css
    const colors = {
        grey: 'rgb(72, 85, 106)',
        purple: 'rgb(117, 65, 200)',
        coal: 'rgb(25, 33, 46)',
    }

    export const Grid = styled.div`
        display: grid;
        gap: 1.5rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    `

    export const Card = styled.div`
        &:nth-child(5n) {
            grid-column-start: 4;
            grid-row: 1 / span 2;
        }
        &:nth-child(5n+1) {
            background-color: ${colors.purple};
            color: white;
            grid-column: span 2;
        }
        &:nth-child(5n+2) {
            background-color: ${colors.grey};
            color: white;
        }
        &:nth-child(5n+3) {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
        &:nth-child(5n+4) {
            background-color: ${colors.coal};
            color: white;
            grid-column: span 2;
        }
        &:nth-child(5n+5) {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
        &:nth-child(10n) {
            grid-column-start: 4;
            grid-row: 3 / span 2;
        }
    `

    export const FlexBox = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
        `

    export const Image = styled.img`
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 1.75rem;
    `

    export const Name = styled.h2`
        font-size: 1rem;
    `

    export const Info = styled.p`
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    `

    export const Title = styled.p`
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    `

    export const Content = styled.p`
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below.

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* dont forget this to fill all the tracks */
  grid-auto-rows:100px; /* the height of one row */
  grid-gap:5px;
}
.grid :nth-child(5n + 1),
.grid :nth-child(5n + 4) {
  grid-column:span 2; /* 1st and 4th need 2 columns */
}
.grid :nth-child(5n + 5) { 
  grid-area: span 2/4; /* 5th at column 4 taking 2 rows */
}
.grid :nth-child(5n + 3) {
  grid-column: 1; /* 3rd at column 1 */
}

/**/
.grid {
  max-width:600px;
  margin:auto;
  counter-reset:num;
}
.grid *{
  border:2px solid;
  font-size:30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center;
}
.grid *:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea about the **grid-auto-flow: dense** property.